# Can any one tell me how the conduit.com works?

Tags: c#, toolbar

Can any one tell me how the conduit.com works??

Hi i want to make something like conduit.com...how this website works.means how they generate an executable in runtime.i want to make in C# and Asp.net..

Please help

thank you

---

What i am asking is that how it generates installation files dynamically...

Comment: You're aware that Conduit sells customized toolbar add-ons for browsers, right?  Are you asking how their website works, or are you asking how to make toolbars for browsers?

Comment: Wow your question is way too general.  You need to think of specific issue or roadblock that you are having and give use more detail, then maybe we can answer your question.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific if you want the stackoverflow.com to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"how it generates installation files dynamically"

Probably using something like nullsoft NSIS - http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page.

They'd make a generic install script, and replace a few files as per the customised toolbar, and then re-run the NSIS compiler and send you its output.

-edit- Another option is InnoSetup - http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php - I've used it before and it's quite good.